# Zotero and BibTeX: citation keys containing underscore are unusable

Tags: bibtex, zotero

I am using Zotero to maintain my library. Up to now it is working fine. I am writing a report in LaTeX and am generating the `.bib` file with Zotero. I just select the items I want to be in the bibliography, then right click and "export elements". Then select "BibTeX" and I get a nice `.bib` file to use with my LaTeX file.

The problem is that Zotero is creating the citation keys in the format `author_title_year` and it seems that **the character `_` is not supported in the citation keys**. (I am getting an error when I try to compile the LaTeX file.) If I manually edit the `.bib` file and change the citation keys to `AuthorTitleYear` then it works ok. Does anyone know how can I tell Zotero to not use `_` in citation keys? Or how can I make BibTeX to accept underscores in the citation keys? (This last option would be nicer.)

Comment: Both `biblatex` and BibTeX usually have no problems with `_` in entry keys (elsewhere they may cause an error outside of math mode, but in entry keys they are fine). So if you get an error, something else must be the culprit. I'm not sure about Zotero itself, but https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/ can help you customise the exported cite key.